# How to use font in the references library?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have dll It my custom control. I need to use font in dll from resources from the app.

I wrote code but it working if font installed on PC.

> new Typeface(new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Astro;Component/Fonts")

How to solve it problem? I need use font without install on PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulate the custom control inside it's own assembly, you shouldn't have a reference to the applications assembly from there. Embed the font files as resources inside your custom control project or define a distinct styling project which is then referenced from your custom control and your application as well.

[image: project]

You can then define and use XAML font families as resources as shown below. The XAML is placed inside `Fonts.xaml` which is located in the same folder as the font files:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ColaborateThin">./#Colaborate Thin</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ColaborateRegular">./#Colaborate Regular</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ColaborateBold">./#Colaborate Bold</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="DroidSansRegular">./#Droid Sans Regular</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="SegoeRegular">Segoe</FontFamily>

<Style x:Key="H1">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ColaborateThin}" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="21px" />
    <Setter Property ="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
</Style>
```